# Change all values in string of format "key=value&..."

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I have a string:

```
var data = 'key1=value1&key2=value2&...';
```

String has a huge number of keys-values combinations. I need to change all values, by some rule - `encodeURIComponent` it. I need to do that only relatively to values (and maybe keys), but now for the whole string.

Is there complete algorithm to do that?

Comment: you probably want to use URLSearchParams - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: @DerekPollard, yeah I think it is good one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to create an object out of the data:

```js
var data="key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3";
var obj=Object.fromEntries(
    data.split("&").reduce((acc,cv)=>{
    acc.push(cv.split("="));
    return acc;
  },[])
);
console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Then you can access whichever key you want and get it's value, say:

```
obj["key2"]
```

You might need to `unescape` values.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote!
May I get a selected answer too, please?

Comment: Please up-vote as well - that's how privileges get unlocked - thanks!

Comment: Actually, @DerekPollard comment is more useful, it is mire easy to use, and it has more features.